# How i block part of the content for unprivileged users

Tags: javascript, html, css, locking

I am doing a web in where I want to prevent an user to access a content before he or she fulfill some predefined goal.

For example, I want to prevent an user to go to certain place of my page until they go to another place before. Like to prevent someone without the proper level to access that part of the web.

I want to avoid the use of password if possible.

I am going to use it in several parts of my webpage.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use somehting like a JS session to check if the user has fulfilled your requirements and if not redirect them to an area where they can do so

Comment: HOw i said, i am still green so... How do i do that?

Comment: I know what you said, but this site is not a place for other people to do the work for you. Google search Javascript sessions and try to put something together. Then come back with code that you have tried and *then* the community will be willing to help you.

Comment: Undestand, sorry if i overask i just wanted a little more of information. Thanks for the help

Comment: Or you could use PHP sessions, it would be really easy

Comment: Its fine just get out there and try things. There is so much info on the web (especially SO). To be a little more descriptive: you can use Javascript sessions to create a session, then on the page you want to hide you look to see if that session was created..if not...redirect them to a page where they do something (fill out a form, click a link, etc)...which sets the session and grants them access when they go back

Comment: Yes you could defintely use PHP sessions too, I just suggested JS causes its client side and OP appeared to not want to use server side (`I want to avoid the use of password`)

Comment: Is that having to give a password to the user for everytime they want to access a place don't sound very "user friendly" more a pain in the ...

Comment: But thanks man, i will try what you said to see if it works. It sounds complicated but i will make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use php session to do this. on your page that you want to restrict access to could have the following code:

```
<?php
session_start() // this starts the php session
if($_SESSION['auth'] !== 'true') // this checks if the session variable "auth" 
                                 // is not true
{
    header("Location: /homepage.php"); // if "auth" is not true, it will redirect 
                                       // back to your home page. you can switch 
                                       // out "/homepage.html" with whatever your 
                                       // actual page is.
}
?>
<html>
<body>Rest of html content...
```

and the home page would look something like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); // starts the session
$buttonClicked=$_POST['access']; // checks to see if the button has been clicked 
if($buttonClicked) {
    $_SESSION['auth'] = 'true'; // sets the session variable auth to true so user 
                                // can have access to other page
    header("Location: /otherpage.php"); // sends the user to the other page
}
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="homepage.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Go to other page" name="access" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks the html button it will send them to the "otherpage.php" and they will be able to get in. both pages need to be .php not .html though.

Comment: I understand this way better. About you answer, i am go to use this in more than one page at a time. Is this go to make my webpage bigger and slowler to work for the user?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example to your question:

1. **index.php** redirects the user to **login.php** if a specified $_SESSION variable does not exist.
2. **login.php** contains a basic account/password form. **login.php** use AJAX to call **checkLogin.php** to check whether the account/password are correct.
3. **checkLogin.php** checks whether the account/password are correct by comparing the user inputs with the data in database(mySQL in this example).
4. If the account/password are correct, **checkLogin.php** initiate $_SESSION["account"] and redirect the user back to **index.php**.

---

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
ob_start();

// Redirect to login.php if $_SESSION["account"] is not set
$url = "login.php";
if(isset($_SESSION["account"])!=true)
{
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your secret contents here-->
    <h1>Hello, your name is:</h1>
    <?php echo $_SESSION["account"]; ?>
</body>
```

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function AjaxCheck()
        {
        if(document.getElementById("account").value==""){
            document.getElementById("div_message").innerHTML = "You are not logged in.";
            return;
        };
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            if(xmlhttp.responseText.match("redirect")){
                window.location.href =  "index.php";
            }
            else{document.getElementById("div_message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
            }
          }
          // Use HTTP get to send user input account/password to checkLogin.php
        xmlhttp.open("GET","checkLogin.php?account="+document.getElementById("account").    value+"&password="+document.getElementById("password").value,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>Account: </p>
        <input type="text" name="account" id = "account"/>
        <p>Password: </p>
        <input type="password" name="password" id = "password" />
        <br>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" onClick = "AjaxCheck()">Login</a>
    </form>
    <div id = "div_message" >
        div_message text
    </div>
</body>
```

**checkLogin.php**

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();

// NOTE: In real world, you should do some sanitization first
$account=$_GET["account"];
$password=$_GET["password"];

checkIfLogin();

function checkIfLogin(){
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","YourDatabaseAccount","YourDatabasePassword");
    if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());} 

    mysql_select_db("YourDB", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `YourTable` WHERE `Account` = '".$GLOBALS['account']."' "    );    
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row==NULL){echo "This account does not exist"; mysql_close($con); return;}
    if(strcmp($row['Password'],SHA1($GLOBALS['password']))==0){
        $_SESSION['account'] = $GLOBALS['account']; 
        echo "redirect" ;
    }
    else{echo "Incorrect Password" ;}

    mysql_close($con);
}

?>
```

---

**Notes**

1. The above example codes "work" but should be consider "dirty", just a quick example.
2. I know you want the answer as simple as possible, but an example with account/password should get you to know the feel how session or cookies work. You can implement the way you like later.
3. You may find these sites/topics useful:

   - [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)
   - [PHP 5 Sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)
   - [PHP 5 Complete Form Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)
   - [PHP 5 Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp)
   - [basic SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp), and things about general Database and SQL.

P.S. Actually you don't need AJAX to achieve your goal, but why not learn more? :)

---

Edit: Just in case that you don't have a database available, here is a simple **checkLogin.php** which only allows user "John" with password "123" to pass.

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();

$account=$_GET["account"];
$password=$_GET["password"];

checkIfLogin();

function checkIfLogin(){
    if(strcmp($GLOBALS['account'],"John")!=0){
        echo "Invalid Account";
    }else if(strcmp($GLOBALS['password'],"123")!=0){
        echo "Incorrect Password";
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['account'] = $GLOBALS['account'];
        echo "redirect" ;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I understand superficially. I must learn php to do what i want. Thanks for the help because this answer and the others give me the lead to what i should learn next. I highly appreciated

Comment: I added a simpler checkLogin.php example, and some learning resources you may be interested in. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: The other answer is really more what the OP was looking for